Is it possible to enable the Relay Kit for an existing safe?
I have a safe recently created which is compatible with Relay Kit but it was initialy created with @safe-global/protocol-kit and already has transactions.
I am attempting to enable and use Safe4337Module from @safe-global/relay-kit but in the documentation says that I can instantiate the class Safe4337Module with options to create/deploy a new safe with the module enabled (which is great) or connect an existing safe with the module already enabled. So basically I am missing the part where I enable the module for a Safe created before without the module enabled. Is this possible?
I can see that the @safe-global/protocol-kit has a method called enableModule which it looks like it is meant to do this but not sure how to use it.
Any help is appreciated.

You can use the protocol kit's method createEnableModuleTx with the correct module address for your network to create the transaction. You can then approve/execute it like any other Safe transaction.
I hope I answered your question. If I did, could you kindly mark it as solved? If not, please let me know 
Thank you in advance!
Best,
Louis

Thanks for the answer, trying it out...
